# Is it supposed to be too slow to use jQuery accordion in Mobile Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented jQuery accordion on my web page.
It's working perfect but too slow to open whole content after I clicked it.
Is it normal?

I tried it with my Android(Kinda new model) but too laggy(slow) to complete:(

my code is just like this

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");   
        $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: You could look into CSS animations.  It'll let you do the same thing, but at higher speeds (native code vs JavaScript).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Thanks. All I want to do is shrink and expand back. I don't need animation that much. What would be the best?

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/gnprv) close to what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to avoid doing javascript animations on mobile devices. Those devices generally don't have enough resources to make it a smooth experience. Here's a (very long but good) article on why part http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/